# Samsung Internet on Emulated AVD wont install

Tags: appium, android

We wish to be able to test Samsung Internet with Appium but are not able to install Samsung Internet on an AVD created by Android Studio.

Does anyone know how to install this or know of any other way to test Samsung Internet with Appium ?

[image: Samsung AVD Screenshot]

Comment: I also tried it with different methods but non of them was applicable. It always stuck about compatibility.